# generic class as associated type

Tags: swift, generics

**when I do:**

```
class GenericClass<T> {}

protocol Protocol {
    associatedtype A
    associatedtype C : GenericClass<A>
}

class IntClass : GenericClass<Int> {}

struct Adopter : Protocol {
    typealias A = Int
    typealias C = IntClass
}
```

everything is ok

but if I add a method to `Protocol` that uses the `C` associated type:

```
protocol Protocol {
    ...
    func f(c: C)
}
```

and implement it in `Adopter`:

```
struct Adopter : Protocol {
    ...
    func f(c: C) {}
}
```

everything brakes! The compiler tells me:

> "Protocol requires function 'use(c:)' with type '(Adopter.C) -> ()'..."

My best guess is that this has something to do with the fact that C is a class and that the type signature f(c: C) would allow subclasses of C being passed but I can't see how that would be a problem...

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jameslintaylor/d9adc72bfaac1eb03eb9f069a34f0505#file-generic-class-as-associated-type-swift) illustrating the problem that you can paste into a playground

I'm wondering if this is a bug? I hope I'm not *again* fundamentally misunderstanding something with the type system

### update

I think I am getting to the root of the problem by just declaring the protocol like this:

```
protocol Protocol {
    associatedtype A
    associatedtype C : GenericClass<A>
    func f(c: C)
}
```

putting this into a playground, I get the error:

> Playground execution failed: error: generic parameter 'C' cannot be a subclass of both 'GenericClass<<< error type >>>' and 'GenericClass'

just because, I tried mimicking a similar type relationship with a struct:

```
struct Struct<
    A,
    C : GenericClass<A>
> {
    func f(c: C) {}
}
```

This compiles just fine.

Comment: This is probably just a bug in the compiler. You're pushing the type system too hard. If possible, avoid mixing complicated inheritance with protocols. It tends to blow up, sometimes because the compiler can't prove it's right, and sometimes because it can't *be* proven to be right. In my experience, your `Struct` is often a much simpler solution and complicated protocols create more headaches than they solve. http://chris.eidhof.nl/post/protocol-oriented-programming/ http://www.thedotpost.com/2016/01/rob-napier-beyond-crusty-real-world-protocols

Comment: After bumping my head into this for too long today I was thinking it might be so... currently refactoring my code to use a simple struct (probably a good thing as you pointed out!). Thanks for the input!